# Restricting applications that access the internet on android

Tags: android

Is there a way(with android code) to select which application can access the internet or uses 3G Data connection without rooting the device? I have researched on this for months now and nothing tangible seems to be coming up. This is a final year project and I need to come up with an acceptable solution.

Comment: You might be able to do something with broadcast receivers.

Comment: Can you give an example or elaborate more?

Comment: You should be able to disable connectivity for the entire device - e.g.  disable mobile data by changing the APN settings to junk and use a WifiManager to kill WiFi whenever it connects. Disabling a specific app will of course require root (and quite possibly a customized rom).

Comment: Thanks jens. But do you think there might be any other way to accomplish this other than by rooting of customizing the rom?

Answer (score 0):

use this `if(manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected())` this a useful condition when application trying to Access wifi us this 
  `else if  (manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnected()) useful when application trying to access 3g`